# Counting words using LinkedList

Tags: c#, list

I have a class WordCount which has string wordDic and int count. Next, I have a List.

I have ANOTHER List which has lots of words inside it. I am trying to use List to count the occurrences of each word inside List.

Below is where I am stuck.

```
class WordCount
{
string wordDic;
int count;

}


    List<WordCount> usd = new List<WordCount>();

    foreach (string word in wordsList)
    {
        if (usd.wordDic.Contains(new WordCount {wordDic=word, count=0 }))
           usd.count[value] = usd.counts[value] + 1;
        else
            usd.Add(new WordCount() {wordDic=word, count=1});

    }
```

I don't know how to properly implement this in code but I am trying to search my List to see if the word in wordsList already exists and if it does, add 1 to count but if it doesn't then insert it inside usd with count of 1.

**Note:** **I have to use Lists to do this. I am not allowed to use anything else like hash tables...**

Comment: First off, you are using `usd` in the loop when you want to use `word` (I assume). You can't use `usd` since a `List` has no `wordDic` property. Second, what type is `count`? You assign a string to it, but then assign it as an `int`.

Comment: Yeah, for count I think it should be null instead since it is an integer not string but the rest of the stuff I am really confused about. usd is my dictionary while wordsList is the populated text I am searching. usd holds the word as well as count of each word. See my update.

Comment: `int` is not nullable. Best to have it default to 0.

Comment: @TheDude I set the proper value now of 0 but still I don't know how to add 1 to the usd object that has the same wordDic as word in wordsList.

Comment: @TheDude your solution was just what I was looking for. Everyone else is suggesting other methods but I clearly said that I cannot use anything other than Lists...I am having some error for syntax with your code in "else" part of the code. I think brackets aren't closed properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the answer before you edited to only use lists...btw, what is driving that requirement?

```
List<string> words = new List<string> {...};

// For case-insensitive you can instantiate with 
// new Dictionary<string, int>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
Dictionary<string, int> counts = new Dictionary<string, int>(); 
foreach (string word in words)
{
    if (counts.ContainsKey(word))
    { 
        counts[word] += 1;
    }
    else
    {
        counts[word] = 1;
    }
}
```

If you can only use lists, Can you use `List<KeyValuePair<string,int>> counts` which is the same thing as a dictionary (although I'm not sure it would guarantee uniqueness).  The solution would be very similar.  If you can only use lists the following will work.

```
        List<string> words = new List<string>{...};
        List<string> foundWord = new List<string>();
        List<int> countWord = new List<int>();
        foreach (string word in words)
        {
            if (foundWord.Contains(word))
            {
                countWord[foundWord.IndexOf(word)] += 1;
            }
            else
            {
                foundWord.Add(word);
                countWord.Add(1);
            }
        }
```

Using your WordCount class

```
        List<string> words = new List<string>{...};
        List<WordCount> foundWord = new List<WordCount>();
        foreach (string word in words)
        {
            WordCount match = foundWord.SingleOrDefault(w => w.wordDic == word);
            if (match!= null)
            {
                match.count += 1;
            }
            else
            {
                foundWord.Add(new WordCount { wordDic = word, count = 1 });
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can someone let me know what is wrong with this solution.  This was beindg created previous to the edit of lists only.

Comment: I marked it back up as it's the fastest and most efficient way. Linq is great but not always the most efficient. It gets way over used especially in the wrong context i.e performance,

Comment: @Baldrick ...fixed the typos

Comment: @codematrix: Agreed re. linq - it is overused, but I find it safer. I prefer to use linq as default (as it's clearer and less error prone), then performance tune using other techniques where needed. But I'm not a fan of the blind must-do-everything-with-linq-at-all-costs philosophy.

Comment: @Harrison I cannot use 2 lists for this task. I HAVE to use a list with WordCount class objects inside. This is a big pain in the rear...

Comment: @HarrisCalvin ... updated to use your WordCount class.  I used linq in the solution.

Comment: @Harrison thank you so much! my head was starting to hurt from all the thinking.

Comment: @Harrison I am getting a bunch of missing ), ; , invalid { errors at the  WordCount match = foundWord.SingleOrDefault(w => w.wordDic == word); and at the else statement's condition. Am I suppose to import linq or something to make use of the =>?

Comment: @HarrisCalvin.  Yes.  For the `SingleOrDefault` you need to have *`using System.Linq;`* at the top and reference the *System.Core* assembly

Answer (score 1):

You can use Linq to do this.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    List<string> wordsList = new List<string>()
    {
        "Cat",
        "Dog",
        "Cat",
        "Hat"
    };

    List<WordCount> usd = wordsList.GroupBy(x => x)
                                   .Select(x => new WordCount() { wordDic = x.Key, count = x.Count() })
                                   .ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use linq: Assuming your list of words :

```
string[] words = { "blueberry", "chimpanzee", "abacus", "banana", "abacus","apple", "cheese" };
```

You can do:

```
var count =
   from word in words
   group word.ToUpper() by word.ToUpper() into g
   where g.Count() > 0
   select new { g.Key, Count = g.Count() };
```

(or in your case, select new WordCount()... it'll depend on how you have your constructor set up)...

the result will look like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should use a Dictionary as its faster when using the "Contains" method.

Just replace your list with this

Dictionary usd = new Dictionary();

```
foreach (string word in wordsList)
{
    if (usd.ContainsKey(word.ToLower()))
       usd.count[word.ToLower()].count++;
    else
        usd.Add(word.ToLower(), new WordCount() {wordDic=word, count=1});

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, all of your class member is private, thus, they could not be accessed somewhere out of your class. Let's assume you're using them in `WordCount` class too.

Second, your `count` member is an `int`. Therefore, follow statement will not work:

```
usd.count[value] = usd.counts[value] + 1;
```

And I think you've made a mistype between `counts` and `count`.

To solve your problem, find the counter responding your word. If it exists, increase count value, otherwise, create the new one.

```
foreach (string word in wordsList) {
    WordCount counter = usd.Find(c => c.wordDic == word);
    if (counter != null) // Counter exists
        counter.count++;
    else
        usd.Add(new WordCount() { wordDic=word, count = 1 }); // Create new one
}
```